# What's the different between these two results?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import gym

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")

print (env.observation_space.shape)
print (env.observation_space.shape[0])
```

The result is

```
(4,)
4
```

I don't understand what's the difference between (4,) and 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, to create a tuple you must give it at least two numbers. If you only want a tuple with one then you need to still separate that number with a comma, as in (4,).

https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/cf25sq/dont_understand_what_does_it_mean_4/

Answer (score 2):

`env.observation_space.shape` is a tuple not a list. Getting its value at index 0 returns the first element, which is 4.

Comment: what's the meaning when it shows (4,)? Does it mean it is a tuple?

Comment: yes, you can try to do `type((4,))` and see that it is a tuple.

Comment: what does the (4,) mean? why there is an empty value (4, "why here is empty?") after 4?

Answer (score 0):

`(4,)` represents the shape of your observation space. The output is ('row','column').

`print (env.observation_space.shape[0])`  the [0] index shows the number of rows

Comment: Why column info is empty in this case?

Comment: It's not empty, it's inconsistent, thus the column cannot assign an appropriate number.

 E.g Row 1 : 3 columns, Row 2: 2 columns

Comment: sorry, I still can't get it. print (env.observation_space.shape) then you mean the column is inconsistent?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the offical doc:http://gym.openai.com/docs/#spaces

UPDATE: https://www.gymlibrary.dev/

`env.observation_space.shape` is 1 dim tuple.

So, `env.observation_space.shape` returns (4,)

`env.observation_space.shape[0]` returns 4

Comment: that link is outdated

Comment: The link has changed to https://www.gymlibrary.dev/ @JAMSHAID